# How can I get Xcode's source control to ignore the Remotes of a git submodule?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, git-submodules

I have an iOS app. This iOS app uses [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for a networking library.

According to the latest way Alamofire's documentation works, the suggested way to add it is as a "submodule" via git. This basically works. On GitHub, it actually shows up as being linked to a different repository at a particular revision.

I'm also trying to use it in a widget in iOS 8 and I'm getting a warning

`ld: warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions`

The short version of how to fix this is to tweak a build option in the Build Settings of the library's project.

This is a problem because it registers to Xcode as me trying to modify the Alamofire project and commit it. Naturally I have no access or rights to push an update to the Alamofire repository and I wouldn't want to.

Is there a way to get Xcode to ignore git submodules? Or maybe explain to git in general that I don't own these other repositories so ignore any changes I made to them? Or maybe a better way to tweak the settings and keep it part of my repository and not the submodule's repository? Or should I just not use these libraries as git submodules if I need to do this sort of thing with them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work, but there is a setting under xCode preferences -> Source Control that says: "Add and Remove Files Automatically".

Perhaps if you turn this off you can simply never add your Alamofire modules

Answer (score 0):

I would try importing Alamofire as a framework.  Mattt included embedded framework support for iOS 8 as of [issue #122.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/112) Then select the framework target -> General tab -> check "Allow app extension API only".

From apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html):

> To configure an app extension target to use an embedded framework, set the target’s “Require Only App-Extension-Safe API” build setting to Yes. If you don’t, Xcode reminds you to do so by displaying the warning “linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions”.